# Is there any way to implement CI/CD for on premises Postgres SQL using Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: postgresql, automation

I want to create one click deployment on azure pipelines to move Postgres Sql changes from dev to QA environment,similar to what we implement using SQL Server Database project where a Powershell script deploy the changes to the remote server.

I have tried pg_dump and psql commands which will create dump file and restore it on the remote server. It does not perform diffing ie(comparing database changes on source and destination , and only replicating the missing changes)

Comment: how is this related to azure devops? your question is how to script postgres backup\restore or something like that

Comment: I need to setup azure devops pipeline for postgres sql for continuous integration and deployment

Answer (score 2):

You've stumbled upon one of the features lacking in the Postgres ecosystem.  One of the more elegant ways to solve migrations using Postgres' own tooling is to package up your migrations as a [Postgres Extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html).  This requires you to generate the deployment scripts yourself, but it is a neat way of applying and packaging up the deployments.

There are a number of commercial tools that will assist in this process, such as [Datical](https://www.datical.com/), [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), and [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).  Note, some of these still require you to generate the change statements yourself, some attempt to create them for you.

Generating change statements is a whole different animal and I recommend you look at schema diffing tools for Postgres to find what best suites your needs.